# OutOfMemoryError with ant.wsimport in gradle

Tags: ant, gradle

How to get rid of the OutOfMemoryError invoking ant.wsimport in Gradle?

```
ant.wsimport(keep: true, destdir: destDir, wsdl: wsdl, wsdlLocation: wsdlLocation, package: destPackage, verbose: false, fork: false, xendorsed: true, xnocompile: true)
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
        at org.gradle.logging.internal.AbstractStyledTextOutput.withStyle(AbstractStyledTextOutput.java:87)
        at org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter.fillInFailureResolution(BuildExceptionReporter.java:191)
        at org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter.formatGenericFailure(BuildExceptionReporter.java:131)
        at org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter.reportBuildFailure(BuildExceptionReporter.java:125)
        at org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter.constructFailureDetails(BuildExceptionReporter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter.renderSingleBuildException(BuildExceptionReporter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter.execute(BuildExceptionReporter.java:72)
        at org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter.buildFinished(BuildExceptionReporter.java:63)
        at org.gradle.BuildLogger.buildFinished(BuildLogger.java:76)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.listener.DefaultListenerManager$LoggerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:174)
        at org.gradle.listener.DefaultListenerManager$LoggerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:163)
        at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
        at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.buildFinished(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems ant gets executed inside the Gradle JVM.

So the best way to control memory settings for the Gradle JVM is via org.gradle.jvmargs=... in gradle.properties.

> org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxPermSize=512M